# Is it necessary to make a deep copy for an immutable object

Tags: java, reference, immutability, deep-copy

Is there ever a reason to make a deep copy of an array of references to immutable objects?

Comment: If the objects in the array be immutable, then is there any possibility of your code changing them?

Comment: I dont think its necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A (shallow) copy of the array will have all the references to the immutable objects at the time of the copying. No matter what happens with the original array, the copy will always have the same state as at the time of the copying.

Deep copying of immutable objects (or arrays of immutable objects) would make sense only if you wanted to have two equal but distinct immutable objects.